# PHP multiple simultaneous requests

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using mongoDB with a collection called user_log.

I used to store all request from the server to database,

Here is the code:

```
$document=null;
$userId="someID";
$cursor = $this->collection->find(array('userID' => $userId));
if ($cursor) {
    $cursor->sort(array('updated_at' => -1))->limit(1);
    if ($cursor->count() > 0) {
        $cursor->getNext();
        $document= $cursor->current();
    }
}
$data = array('userID' => $userId,....);
if($document){
    $data['request_count'] = $document['request_count'] + 1;
}else{
     $data['request_count'] = 1;
}
$data['created_at'] = time();
$data['updated_at'] = time();
$this->collection->insert($data);
```

And then tried to ran a stress test using wrk.

wrk -t4 -c200 -d30s http://localhost:8000/testing/stress-test

The result is 
4 threads and 200 connections
1470 requests in 30.03s, 835.83KB read.

Total 1470 items inserted into db.
The issue is the last created items 'request_count' is 49 instead of 1470!.

Am I doing this in a wrong way? If not, how to resolve this isse?